# Dropdown list with ng-options is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc, dropdown, ng-options

Hey every one I am populating a drop-down list getting value from database then storing it in  **Category** type list 
here is class of Category

```
 public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int main_category_Id { get; set; }
    public string Main_Category { get; set; }
}
```

And storing values in above type Collection 
Below here is code for getting values from Db and returning as a json object

```
  public JsonResult getcategory()
    {
        IEnumerable<Category> catgry_list;
        //calling the category interface method
        catgry_list =   repository.category_List;
        // var data = s_list;
        return new JsonResult (new { Data=catgry_list });
    }
```

Below here is code of angular controller where i am receiving that type list

```
 LocationService.getcategory().then(function (d) {
    $scope.cat_list = d.data;
},
```

In above section **cat_list ** is variable which is declared within Scope that code is below

```
 $scope.cat_list = null;
```

**getcategory()** is a function  which code is below

```
 fac.getcategory = function () {
    return $http.get('/Admin/getcategory');

}
```

below here is my front-end drop-down code

```
 <Select  ng-model="catgryid" ng-options="I.main_category_Id as I.Main_Category for I in cat_list" class="form-control"
                      >

            </Select>
```

when i run my application it shows **undefined** I debug it in chrome its Shows that **cat_list** having values but it show only undefined

I am unable to understand that what is  **undefined** what is the solution about this

Comment: why are you calling  gettsubcategory on select change

Comment: thats not related to it , On this i am calling another function which get subcategory list on changing the value in category drop-down

Comment: I did it but its not working yet

Comment: ng-options="I in cat_list" use this one

Comment: Sir its not working **I in cat_list** and ng-options syntax in angular documentation is that **Select as key for value in array/List** .

Answer (score 0):

1st thing, you don't need `as I.Main_Category` here in this line...

```
I.main_category_Id as I.Main_Category for I in cat_list
```

change this to this one

```
I.main_category_Id for I in cat_list
```

Then comes to your issue, So I guess Issue is in your json object..

> return new JsonResult (new { Data=catgry_list });

You are sending list as a json object... It will return something like this

`data : [{lstObj1},{lstObj2},{lstObj3},,,]`

So when you try to traverse this 'data', it gives whole list `{lstObj1},{lstObj2},{lstObj3},,,`  but you are expecting `lstObj` and treating it as a list object that's whhy it returns you `undefined` (hope you understand what I'm saying)

So the easiest solution is `Don't convert you list into another json object, pass it as it is, it will definitely work`

Comment: that's really working and my issue is resolved now.  I am thinking that any legend can help me to fix this issue. so thank's a lot legend